# Missing number, treated as zero. \begin{tabularx}{| @{}X | @{}X | @{}X |}

Tags: tables, tabularx

Here is my practise table 
, I wrote if after watching some youtube videos and reading [wikibooks tables tutorial.](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables)
This is not generating pdf

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{siunitx}
%\sisetup{
%round-mode = places,
%round-precision = 2, 
%}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabularx}{| @{}X | @{}X | @{}X |}
\hline
\textbf{Value 1} & \textbf{Value 2} & \textbf{Value 3}\\
$\alpha$ & $\beta$ & $\gamma$ \\
\hline
1 & 1110.1 & a \\
2 & 10.1  & b \\
3 & 23.113231 & c \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{center}
\caption{Your first label}
\label{tab:table1}
\end{table}
Second table
\begin{table} [h!]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|r | l |}
    \hline
    7C0 & hexadecimal \\
    3700 & octal \\
    \cline{2-2} 11111000000 & binary \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\caption{Your second label}
\label{tab:table2}
\end{table}


\begin{tabular}{cc}
    boring cell content & \parbox[t]{5cm}{rather long par\\new par}
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{c c}
    \hline
    \begin{verbatim}
    code
    \end{verbatim}
    & description
    \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

I am getting following errors

```
line 15: Missing number, treated as zero. \begin{tabularx}{| @{}X | @{}X | @{}X |}
line 15: Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). \begin{tabularx}{| @{}X | @{}X | @{}X |}
line 24: Package array Error: Illegal pream-token (\hline): `c' used. \end{tabularx}
line 24: Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr. \end{tabularx}
line 24: Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr. \end{tabularx}
line 24: Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr. \end{tabularx}
line 24: Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr. \end{tabularx}
line 24: Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr. \end{tabularx}
line 24: Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr. \end{tabularx}
line 24: Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr. \end{tabularx}
line 24: Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr. \end{tabularx}
line 24: Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr. \end{tabularx}
line 24: Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr. \end{tabularx}
line 24: Package array Error: Illegal pream-token (\hline): `c' used. \end{tabularx}
line 24: Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr. \end{tabularx}
line 24: Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr. \end{tabularx}
line 24: Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr. \end{tabularx}
line 24: Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr. \end{tabularx}
line 24: Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr. \end{tabularx}
line 24: Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr. \end{tabularx}
line 24: Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr. \end{tabularx}
line 24: Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr. \end{tabularx}
line 24: Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr. \end{tabularx}
line 24: Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr. \end{tabularx}
line 51: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. \begin{verbatim}
line 51: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. \begin{verbatim}
line 51: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. \begin{verbatim}
line 51: Missing \endgroup inserted. \begin{verbatim}
line 51: Missing \endgroup inserted. \begin{verbatim}
line 51: Missing } inserted. \begin{verbatim}
line 51: Missing \cr inserted. \begin{verbatim}
line 51: Missing } inserted. \begin{verbatim}
line 51: Missing \cr inserted. \begin{verbatim}
line 51: Misplaced \cr. \begin{verbatim}
line 51: Missing \cr inserted. \begin{verbatim}
line 51: Misplaced \cr. \begin{verbatim}
line 51: Missing \cr inserted. \begin{verbatim}
line 51: Misplaced \cr. \begin{verbatim}
line 51: Missing \cr inserted. \begin{verbatim}
line 51: Misplaced \cr. \begin{verbatim}
line 51: Missing \cr inserted. \begin{verbatim}
line 51: Misplaced \cr. \begin{verbatim}
line 51: Missing \cr inserted. \begin{verbatim}
line 51: Misplaced \cr. \begin{verbatim}
line 51: Missing \cr inserted. \begin{verbatim}
line 51: Misplaced \cr. \begin{verbatim}
line 51: Missing \cr inserted. \begin{verbatim}
line 51: Misplaced \cr. \begin{verbatim}
line 51: Missing \cr inserted. \begin{verbatim}
line 51: Misplaced \cr. \begin{verbatim}
line 51: Missing \cr inserted. \begin{verbatim}
line 51: Misplaced \cr. \begin{verbatim}
line 51: Missing \cr inserted. \begin{verbatim}
line 51: Misplaced \cr. \begin{verbatim}
line 51: Missing \cr inserted. \begin{verbatim}
line 51: Misplaced \cr. \begin{verbatim}
line 51: Missing \cr inserted. \begin{verbatim}
line 51: Misplaced \cr. \begin{verbatim}
line 51: Missing \cr inserted. \begin{verbatim}
line 51: Misplaced \cr. \begin{verbatim}
line 51: Missing \cr inserted. \begin{verbatim}
line 51: Misplaced \cr. \begin{verbatim}
line 51: Missing \cr inserted. \begin{verbatim}
line 51: Misplaced \cr. \begin{verbatim}
line 51: Missing \cr inserted. \begin{verbatim}
line 51: Misplaced \cr. \begin{verbatim}
line 51: Missing \cr inserted. \begin{verbatim}
line 51: Misplaced \cr. \begin{verbatim}
line 51: Missing \cr inserted. \begin{verbatim}
line 51: Misplaced \cr. \begin{verbatim}
line 51: Missing \cr inserted. \begin{verbatim}
line 51: Misplaced \cr. \begin{verbatim}
line 51: Missing \cr inserted. \begin{verbatim}
line 51: Misplaced \cr. \begin{verbatim}
line 51: Missing \cr inserted. \begin{verbatim}
line 51: Misplaced \cr. \begin{verbatim}
line 51: Missing \cr inserted. \begin{verbatim}
line 51: Misplaced \cr. \begin{verbatim}
line 51: Missing \cr inserted. \begin{verbatim}
line 51: Misplaced \cr. \begin{verbatim}
line 51: Missing \cr inserted. \begin{verbatim}
line 51: Misplaced \cr. \begin{verbatim}
line 51: Missing \cr inserted. \begin{verbatim}
line 51: Misplaced \cr. \begin{verbatim}
line 51: Missing \cr inserted. \begin{verbatim}
line 51: Misplaced \cr. \begin{verbatim}
line 51: Missing \cr inserted. \begin{verbatim}
line 51: Misplaced \cr. \begin{verbatim}
line 51: Missing \cr inserted. \begin{verbatim}
line 51: Misplaced \cr. \begin{verbatim}
line 51: Missing \cr inserted. \begin{verbatim}
line 51: Misplaced \cr. \begin{verbatim}
line 51: Missing \cr inserted. \begin{verbatim}
line 51: Misplaced \cr. \begin{verbatim}
line 51: Missing \cr inserted. \begin{verbatim}
line 51: Misplaced \cr. \begin{verbatim}
line 51: Missing \cr inserted. \begin{verbatim}
line 51: Misplaced \cr. \begin{verbatim}
line 51: Missing \cr inserted. \begin{verbatim}
line 51: Misplaced \cr. \begin{verbatim}
line 51: Missing \cr inserted. \begin{verbatim}
line 51: Misplaced \cr. \begin{verbatim}
line 51: Missing \cr inserted. \begin{verbatim}
line 51: Misplaced \cr. \begin{verbatim}
line 51: Missing \cr inserted. \begin{verbatim}
line 51: Misplaced \cr. \begin{verbatim}
line 51: Missing \cr inserted. \begin{verbatim}
line 51: Misplaced \cr. \begin{verbatim}
line 51: Missing \cr inserted. \begin{verbatim}
line 51: Misplaced \cr. \begin{verbatim}
line 51: Missing \cr inserted. \begin{verbatim}
line 51: Misplaced \cr. \begin{verbatim}
line 51: Missing \cr inserted. \begin{verbatim}
line 51: Misplaced \cr. \begin{verbatim}
line 51: Missing \cr inserted. \begin{verbatim}
line 51: Misplaced \cr. \begin{verbatim}
line 51: Missing \cr inserted. \begin{verbatim}
line 51: Misplaced \cr. \begin{verbatim}
line 51: Missing \cr inserted. \begin{verbatim}
line 51: Misplaced \cr. \begin{verbatim}
line 51: Missing \cr inserted. \begin{verbatim}
line 51: Misplaced \cr. \begin{verbatim}
line 51: Missing \cr inserted. \begin{verbatim}
line 51: Misplaced \cr. \begin{verbatim}
line 24: X Columns too narrow (table too wide)(tabularx)
line 24: Overfull \hbox (54.77792pt too wide) in alignment
```

Since I am trying to learn so I would like to know what is the conceptual mistake I did in this code.

Comment: You forgot to specify `tabularx` width: it should be: `\begin{tabularx}{<desired width>}{| @{}X | @{}X | @{}X |}`

Comment: See also my comment to an earlier question of you: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/542928/very-long-time-taken-to-compile-pdf-from-tex-studio#comment1371817_542928

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/542944/197451

Comment: Also, do yourself and your reader a favor and remove all occurences or @{} if you want to keep the vertical lines. Inside of a table you usually have a small horizontal white space left and right of the text inside of a cell (Also called `\tabcolsep`). This white space ensures that the text does not toutch the vertical line or the text in the adjacent columns. With `@{}` you can remove this small space. If you remove this space, the letters will touch the vertical line, which does not look good.

Comment: Some people sometimes use `@{}` in tables to remove the white space left of the first and right of the last column in tables without vertical lines. An example could look like: `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}X X X @{}}`

Comment: Even if you add a width to the `tabularx`, your code will still produce errors. This is due to you using a `verbatim` environment isnide of a `c` type column. You can only use a `verbatim` environment inside of `p{<your width here>}`  (or derived) column types. This was also already mentioned in the comments to one of your previous questions: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/542982/rowcolors-line-31-misplaced-noalign-hline-when-creating-table#comment1371416_542982

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/542982/rowcolors-line-31-misplaced-noalign-hline-when-creating-table#comment1371416_542982 ....

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: This is ecaxtly the comment I liked to in my comment.

Comment: @leandriis sorry yes I noticed that later:-) (the ping to you was only an indication of shared pain:-)

Comment: also the table is a table of numerical data with no linebreaking in the cells so would look much better set as a `tabular` at its natural width, why are you forcing the table to be full width?

Comment: @leandriss Yes I had seen your comment that time I was not able to understand fully what you said. For verbatim environment  I watched all videos here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CIyVtkg1bag and the code with verbatim inside c is given [on wikibooks tables tutorial](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables) in small heading **Other environments inside tables** So I got a bit of understanding of verbatim but since on wikibooks they mentioned that example so I was trying that example as given on their page. Thanks for your patience to reply to same mistake again.

Comment: For tabularx I am reading http://ctan.imsc.res.in/macros/latex/required/tools/tabularx.pdf but here they did not mention that specifying column width is mandatory with tabularx so I am having that doubt, or may be if they specified I am not able catch the lines in ctan pdf.

Comment: @koeradoera: Regarding the `verbatim`: The wikibook entry you linked to in your qeustion also sais: "you might encounter errors similar to `! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.`  
To solve this problem, change column specifier to "paragraph" (p, m or b). " directly underneath the example table you copied. This is also the error message you will get from your code provided that you eliminate the `tabularx`related error.

Comment: Regarding the `tabularx` documentation: The first page mentiones the syntax `\begin{tabularx}{〈width〉}[〈pos〉]{〈preamble〉}` with `width` being the width of the whole table and `preamble` being the list of column specifiers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned earlier, the error message you get informs you about the missing width of the `tabularx`:

The correct syntax is `\begin{tabularx}{>table width here<}{>column specifiers here<}`. Example: `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XXX}`.

Since you mentioned in an earlier comment you were inerested in good looking table, I have added some step-by-step examples on how you can improve the layout of this first table. The code contains some hopefully helpful comments to explain the changes and their reasons.

As also already mentioned earlier, the example contains another error: A `verbatim` environment can only be used in a `p` (or derived) column type. I have also corrected that.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{siunitx}
%\sisetup{
%round-mode = places,
%round-precision = 2, 
%}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}



\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| @{}X | @{}X | @{}X |} % added missing width argument \textwidth here
\hline
\textbf{Value 1} & \textbf{Value 2} & \textbf{Value 3}\\
$\alpha$ & $\beta$ & $\gamma$ \\
\hline
1 & 1110.1 & a \\
2 & 10.1  & b \\
3 & 23.113231 & c \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{center}
\caption{syntax corrected}
\label{tab:table1a}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering % removed center environment and used centering command instead. The former adds vertical white space that might be undesired
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| X | X | X |} % Also removed @{} to prevent overlap of the text with the vertical lines
\hline
\textbf{Value 1} & \textbf{Value 2} & \textbf{Value 3}\\
$\alpha$ & $\beta$ & $\gamma$ \\
\hline
1 & 1110.1 & a \\
2 & 10.1  & b \\
3 & 23.113231 & c \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\caption{removed overlap with vertical lines}
\label{tab:table1b}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering 
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X X X} % Entirely removed vertical lines 
\toprule % replaced \hline with booktabs line
\textbf{Value 1} & \textbf{Value 2} & \textbf{Value 3}\\
$\alpha$ & $\beta$ & $\gamma$ \\
\midrule  % replaced \hline with booktabs line
1 & 1110.1 & a \\
2 & 10.1  & b \\
3 & 23.113231 & c \\
\bottomrule  % replaced \hline with booktabs line
\end{tabularx}
\caption{removed vertical lines and used horizontal lines from booktabs}
\label{tab:table1c}
\end{table}


\begin{table}[h!]
\centering 
\begin{tabular}{ccc} % replaced tabularx with a regular tabular. There is no need to artificially make the table wider
\toprule 
\textbf{Value 1} & \textbf{Value 2} & \textbf{Value 3}\\
$\alpha$ & $\beta$ & $\gamma$ \\
\midrule  
1 & 1110.1 & a \\
2 & 10.1  & b \\
3 & 23.113231 & c \\
\bottomrule  
\end{tabular}
\caption{replaced tabularx with tabular. no need to make the table wider}
\label{tab:table1d}
\end{table}


\begin{table}[h!]
\centering 
\begin{tabular}{cS[table-format=4.6] c} % rreplacesd second column with S type column from siunits to improve alignment of numbers
\toprule 
\textbf{Value 1} & \textbf{Value 2} & \textbf{Value 3}\\
$\alpha$ & {$\beta$} & $\gamma$ \\ % adde {} around {$\beta$} because of non-number in S type column  
\midrule  
1 & 1110.1 & a \\
2 & 10.1  & b \\
3 & 23.113231 & c \\
\bottomrule  
\end{tabular}
\caption{used siunitx for second column}
\label{tab:table1d}
\end{table}

\pagebreak


Second table
\begin{table} [h!]
\centering % see table 2
\begin{tabular}{|r | l |}
    \hline
    7C0 & hexadecimal \\
    3700 & octal \\
    \cline{2-2} 11111000000 & binary \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Your second label}
\label{tab:table2}
\end{table}


\begin{tabular}{cc}
    boring cell content & \parbox[t]{5cm}{rather long par\\new par}
\end{tabular}

\bigskip % just for some vertical space in the output. Do not use in actual document!

\begin{tabular}{cp{5cm}} % use a p type column here
    boring cell content & rather long par new par \\ % no need for parbox in every cell (automatic linebreak here)
        boring cell content & rather \newline long text   par new par % no need for parbox in every cell (manual linebreak)
\end{tabular}

\bigskip % just for some vertical space in the output. Do not use in actual document!

\begin{tabular}{p{3cm} c} % verbatim only works in a p type column. Adjust the width to your needs
    \hline
    \begin{verbatim}
    code
    \end{verbatim}
    & description
    \\ \hline
     \verb|code| % for shorter code, use verb. For more improvement give more information about the nature of the code. More advanced packages are listings and minted. Which to use depends on the requirements and the desired output.
    & description
    \\ \hline
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```